# Printing stack trace in readable format using logstash - Newline character not processed by logback logstash JSON appender in Spring boot logger

Tags: logstash, logback, spring-logback

I am trying to print the exception stack trace as:-

```
log.error("Error is  {}" , ArrayUtils.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
```

This prints the entire stack trace in a single line.

I tried replacing every terminal "," character with "\n" but that doesnt work.

I also tried:

```
log.error("Error is \n {}" , ArrayUtils.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
```

But instead of printing on new line, it just prints the newline character as-is:

```
Error is \n java.base. ..... ,\njava.something.....
```

So i want to know how i can include newline in logger... along with the json appender

logback-spring.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- logs to /tmp/spring.log by default -->
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="logstash-json-appender.xml"/>

    <springProfile name="prod | uat | qa | int">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="JSON_CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="default | dev | test | junit">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

logstash-json-appender.xml

```
<included>
    <!--
      Defines a JSON formatted appender for both the console and log files.
      For configuration details, see: 
     -->
    <springProperty scope="context" name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <appender name="JSON_CONSOLE" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LoggingEventAsyncDisruptorAppender">
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
                <providers>
                    <timestamp>
                        <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                    </timestamp>
                    <pattern>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                            "level": "%level",
                            "service": "${appName:-}",
                            "traceId": "%X{traceId:-}",
                            "spanId": "%X{spanId:-}",
                            "parentSpanId": "%X{parentSpanId:-}",
                            "pid": "${PID:-}",
                            "thread": "%thread",
                            "class": "%logger{40}",
                            "message": "%message"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </appender>

    <appender name="JSON_FILE" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LoggingEventAsyncDisruptorAppender">
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </encoder>
            <!-- use the default spring boot conventions here, but leverage a different encoder -->
            <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_FILE_NAME_PATTERN:-${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz}</fileNamePattern>
                <cleanHistoryOnStart>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-false}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
                <maxFileSize>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_MAX_FILE_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-0}</totalSizeCap>
                <maxHistory>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_MAX_HISTORY:-7}</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
    </appender>
</included>
```

Comment: @user1254825 Did you find an answer to this? Looking into this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using:

```
log.error("Error is", e);
```

`Logger` will generally print the stack trace when you append the exception as the last parameter to the call (error, warn, info, debug, trace). Just don't provide a curly-brace placeholder for it.